# High Density Signal Meaning

Tags: eeg, signal-processing

When I was reading an article, I found that it describes the EEG signal as a  *high-density signal*. So what is that mean?

> EMG is high temporal resolution  and moderate spatial resolution
>   (comparable  to high-density EEG)

Comment: Could you please quote the passage from the article, for context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"High-density EEG" refers to the number of electrodes in the array.  Typically, any EEG rig with more than 64 electrodes is considered to be high-density electroencephalography.